# How can I run code after the return statement in a function in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift2, return

Consider the following code:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let validator:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@","[A-Za-z0-9- ]+")
    if(validator.evaluateWithObject(string) || string == "" /* i.e. backspace */) {
        self.process(textField)
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

I want to actually run self.process(textField) AFTER the return statement, because before it, the text in the textField has not actually changed yet. This led me to wonder, why can't I just execute some code *after* the return statement? Why do functions always stop when the return statement happens?

I realize that's traditionally what return *means*, but is there an alternative? Like, is there a way to return a value from a function and then still keep going?

On the one hand this seems like a stupid question, but on the other hand, I feel like I can't be the first person to ever want to do this. It would be good enough if I could fire off something to run on the next cycle of the run loop, so maybe there's something in GCD that would help me.

Comment: Google for Grand Central Dispatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. But the solution to your problem is simple.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let validator:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@","[A-Za-z0-9- ]+")
    if(validator.evaluateWithObject(string) || string == "" /* i.e. backspace */) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("about to process textField, timestamp: \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)")
            self.process(textField)
        }
        print("about to return true, timestamp: \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)")
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

`DispatchQueue.main.async` will defer execution to the next iteration of the run loop. With those `print()` statements you'll see this in the console. Your timestamps will be different but you'll see the small difference (about 15/1000 of a second in this case).

> about to return true, timestamp: 1612578965.103658

> about to process textField, timestamp: 1612578965.1188931

If you require a specific delay use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`

The best explanation I have found on this is Matt Neuburg's book "iOS 14 Programming Fundamentals with Swift". See the Delayed Performance section.

Answer (score 24):

Since Swift 2.0 we have the keyword called "defer". A keyword that allows us to specify a block of code, a segment inside our function that will be executed just before the program control is transferred outside of the scope. Maybe for cleanup or other needs, actions that need to happen even if an error is thrown.

The code execution inside a **defer** block is deferred until the penultimate statement is executed, assuming the case where the last one is a return statement.

Here's how you can use it:

```
func anyFunction(someParameter: Int) -> Int {

    // Some code

    defer {

        // Code to be deferred.

    }

    return someValue

} // anyFunction
```

The position of the **defer** block should be placed anywhere within the curly braces and **always before the return statement**, for logical reasons and also to avoid the warning: "Code after 'return' will never be executed".

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: DO NOT REFER THIS ANSWER :Nothing gets executed after the return Statement. Look at the result of your code : https://ibb.co/kb4Hg9 . It gives a compile time warning. ANSWER TO THE POST : Simply Consider `defer{}` as Destructor of a function. thats it, it gets executed when the function is about to get out of its scope.

Comment: @YashBedi Thanks for clarifying, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @YashBedi You should read the Vote Down page in the Help Center: "Instead of voting down: If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it." Source: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: you happy now .

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to move your process code to another function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    print("view loaded")
    textField.addTarget(self,
        action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
}


func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField){
    print("text changed: \(theTextField.text)")
    self.process(textField)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no language primitive to run arbitrary code after a return statement. No language provides this. However you can always use closures to embed and sequence code flow; like a completion handler.

In some cases you may want to use `willSet` and/or `didSet`. Imagine having a String property that is a backing store for your text field. If the string is validated, then you write to the backing store. That will then trigger `willSet` which can run your `process` code and update the `textField` directly depending on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Defer injections should be at the reachable statements of the code, otherwise they will not be executed at the end of the block. Basically, its the main idea of defer.

Answer (score 0):

Once a function returns, that is the end of that function's called life. To guarantee the execution of something first after a function's return would require the object that called the function to execute that something in a serialized environment.

However, in your use case, that function is invoked by user input and unless we subclass or swizzle our way through this, what I'd recommend in your use case is async dispatching with a non-noticeable delay:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let validator:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@","[A-Za-z0-9- ]+")
    if(validator.evaluateWithObject(string) || string == "" /* i.e. backspace */) {
        self.process(textField)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            // async allows control to fall through
            // delay ensures call after return
        }
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

This is a borderline hack and I personally don't like this kind of solution but the alternative is so much uglier and from the user's end, it would appear seamless. There is definitely room in engineering for heuristics and this is one such case.